# How to install 32-bit libcurl on 64-bit Ubuntu 16?

Tags: apt, libraries

I have a 64-bit library up and working but couldn't install the 32-bit version. I can't use the 64-bit binaries because all the other static libraries I'm using are all compiled for a 32-bit system.
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install 32 bit `libcurl` using the following:

```
# enable i386 packages to be installed (may already be enabled)
dpkg --add-architecture i386
# update apt to fetch metadata for the new architecture
apt update
# install! (note: you may need a different version)
apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386
```

This brings in ~35 or so other `i386` packages as well.

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` shows the current architecture and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` shows any additional architectures.